# how I can personalize the chrome contextmenu?

Tags: google-chrome, contextmenu

I would like, when I select a word in web page and I do a right-clic, have in the contextmenu the possibility :

1) start a program of me (script perl)

and / or

2) can do a seek with the selection in a web page (like google or OPAC ...)

Sorry for my english (can you be very explicit, please)

Thanks, marc

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an extension, there is a [contentMenu API](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/beta/contextMenus.html) that allows extensions to add this functionality. If you're just an end user, you can try looking for what you want in the Chrome Web Store.